# Serving up my xml sitemap in django

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I created my own sitemap for a small site and placed it in the root directory. How do I get django to serve it up? Do I need to edit the urls.py file? How do I code that?

Answer (score 0):

Place it in a template folder, then add it to your urls.py. Here are a few examples from our site:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^crossdomain.xml$',
     TemplateView.as_view(template_name='crossdomain.xml')),
    (r'^robots.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt')),
```

(we generate the sitemap.xml file, so that's not there).